# Returning Data Frame to excel through xlwings UDF

Tags: python, excel, vba, user-defined-functions, xlwings

I'm trying to create a User-Defined Function using Python, Xlwings library and Excel.

The objective is to use a function, let's call ret_data_frames to fill not only the the A1 cell, but all the need cells to return the entire data frame.

Like the images above:

[image]

[image]

The data frame that I used is obtained through web-scraping and have large dimensions, so I let's use a simple data frame and, if this works, I replace the idea to my original code

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def get_data_frame(data):
    dates = pd.date_range(data,periods=6)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=dates,columns=list('ABCD'))
```

After that, it's necessary to create the UDF function

```
import xlwings as xw
from test import get_data_frame

@xw.func
def ret_data_frame(data):
    return get_data_frame(data)
```

This idea isn't working, so, the question is:

It's possible to use UDF's to reproduce dataframes?

Thanks

Comment: If the UDF is entered as an array formula (e.g. select cells A1:D5, then type `=ret_data_frame()` into cell A1 and press Ctrl-Shift-Enter rather than just Enter) then the UDF can return an array (in this case a 5x4 two-dimensional array).  That is how it works with VBA anyway - it may or may not work with xlwings.

Comment: The dimensions of this data frame are dynamic. I though about using an array formula but how can I create a UDF that pastes the entire Data Frame? Using the array idea I don't know what is the dimensions of data frame.

Comment: Without using an array formula, a UDF is theoretically only able to return a single value to the cell containing the function call.  It theoretically can't modify the Excel environment in any other way.  ("Theoretically" - because there are some [fairly dangerous] ways to get around it.)

Comment: Could you add one of the worksheet events (maybe `Worksheet_SelectionChange` or `Worksheet_Calculate` or `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick`) to invoke your function.  The limitations to only updating a single cell apply only to UDFs (i.e. Functions called from an Excel Cell), not to exactly the same code called from an Event.

Comment: Understood. I think that my idea can't be done. You answered my question. If you like, post this solution and I'll accept the answer.

Comment: reading the docs helps: http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/udfs.html#dynamic-array-formulas

Answer (score 3):

This what worked for me:

```
@xw.func
@xw.arg('x', pd.DataFrame, index=False, header=True)
@xw.ret(header=True)
def get_my_df(x):
    return x
```

And there are various ways you can return dataFrame, with this

`@xw.ret(header=True, index=True, expand='table')`

you can return dataFrame immediately into Excel, without a necessity to wrap it into Excel array formulas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the correct xlwings reutrn

> @xw.ret(index=False, header=True, expand='table')

decorator at the top of your function

```
@xw.func
@xw.ret(index=False, header=True, expand='table')
def ret_data_frame(data):
    return get_data_frame(data)
```

Comment: Hi, i know this is an old thread...in this case, the "data" is the name of the dataFrame?

Comment: Hi, data is just and example argument, it can be anything. you can even remove it.  The example is very abstract.  The main point is that you need to have @xw.ret tag